# Solr: copy multi-valued field to single-valued field

Tags: solr, textfield, multivalue

I am working with Solr to do a predictive search.
I have a multi-valued field containing the characteristics of a product (i.e: "blue", "250 GB hard drive", "12cm wide", etc)

I need to have them all together in one field separated by a whitespace: 
"blue 250 GB hard drive 12cm wide"

Is that possible with the copyfield??

If the answer is no, how shall I do it??

thank you!!!

Comment: why does the field need to be single-valued? adding spaces this way is likely to make phrase queries return unexpected results

Comment: because if the user searches for "250 GB hard drive blue" I need the Solr to find the product that has that words in its description. But nowadays I have all the product characteristics as values of a multi-valued attribute.

Comment: It should work, Solr doesn't expect all the query term to appear in the same field value!